# Dynamic For Loop in Visual Basic - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a final project for my entry level visual basic class. I am trying to create a loop that calls a couple functions and dynamically sets variables with the functions' outputs. I need to dynamically define the variables based on the intloop current value. I know this is the wrong way to do it, but what is the right way?

```
        'Counts number of courses total, for credit or not
    If Not txtGradePercentCourse1.Text = "" Then
        intCourseCount += 1
    End If
    If Not txtGradePercentCourse2.Text = "" Then
        intCourseCount += 1
    End If
    If Not txtGradePercentCourse3.Text = "" Then
        intCourseCount += 1
    End If
    If Not txtGradePercentCourse4.Text = "" Then
        intCourseCount += 1
    End If

    'Loops through all courses and calculates letter grade and quality points for each course
    For intloop = 1 To intCourseCount

        dblPercent = CDbl(txtGradePercentCourse1.Text)
            intCredits = CInt(txtCreditsCourse1.Text)
            lblLetterGradeCourse1.Text = PercentToLetterGrade(dblPercent)
            dblQualityPointsCourse4 = CalculateQualityPoints(dblPercent, intCredits)

        dblPercent = CDbl(txtGradePercentCourse2.Text)
            intCredits = CInt(txtCreditsCourse2.Text)
            lblLetterGradeCourse2.Text = PercentToLetterGrade(dblPercent)
            dblQualityPointsCourse2 = CalculateQualityPoints(dblPercent, intCredits)

        dblPercent = CDbl(txtGradePercentCourse3.Text)
            intCredits = CInt(txtCreditsCourse3.Text)
            lblLetterGradeCourse3.Text = PercentToLetterGrade(dblPercent)
            dblQualityPointsCourse3 = CalculateQualityPoints(dblPercent, intCredits)

        dblPercent = CDbl(txtGradePercentCourse4.Text)
            intCredits = CInt(txtCreditsCourse4.Text)
            lblLetterGradeCourse4.Text = PercentToLetterGrade(dblPercent)
        dblQualityPointsCourse4 = CalculateQualityPoints(dblPercent, intCredits)

    Next
```

Comment: Why do you need to loop? Put each course's processing in its `if` statements.

Comment: Are you thinking they should be in an array that you can index into? Have you tried putting them in one to see how that works out?

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with what you have.  Each step touches 3 controls (2 TBs and a label).  Changing it to a function would require passing those controls - just moving the redundancy elsewhere ; much the same with a loop.  Thats the price for using controls in place of variables and such